# How to print an arraylist in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-volley

I'm trying to print an array of objects in my app, but it is returning empty. This is the log that I'm getting:

```
07-02 15:02:44.179  16933-17469/com.representemais I/RM﹕ []
```

I'm using volley to get the data from an API, and I need to print that data using an object array.
I need to see in the log the objects that's inside the array, what I don't know is how can I print the objects. Why it is returning null?

This is the Sync Class:

```
public class Sincronizar {

    private Context context;

    public Sincronizar(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

   public void start() {

    try {

        ClientesRest mClientesRest = new ClientesRest(this.context);

        Log.i("RM", "P1");

        mClientesRest.getClientes(new ClientesRest.ClientesRestListener() {
            public void clientesReceived(List<ClienteModel> clientes) {
                // Here modify to do whatever you need to do with clientes
                Log.i("RM", "P:2");
                Log.i("RM", String.valueOf(clientes));
                Log.i("RM", "P:3");
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("RM", String.valueOf(e.getStackTrace()));
    }

}


    public Integer total() {
        return 100;
    }

}
```

This is the ClientRest:

```
public class ClientesRest extends Servidor {

    private String recursoRest = "clientes";

    List<ClienteModel> arrayClientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue ;



private Context context;
public ClientesRest(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
}

public interface ClientesRestListener {
    public void clientesReceived(List<ClienteModel> clientes);
}

public final void getClientes(final ClientesRestListener listener) {

    String url = this.URL_WS + recursoRest;
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);

    JsonObjectRequest mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            List<ClienteModel> clientes = null;
            try {
                clientes = parseJSON(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i("RM", String.valueOf(e.getStackTrace()));
            }
            listener.clientesReceived(clientes);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("RM", error.getMessage());
        }

    }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("X-API-TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkD0bDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    mRequestQueue.add(mJsonObjectRequest);
}

private List<ClienteModel> parseJSON(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {

    Log.i("RM", "executou o parseJSON");

        /* array para armazenar os clientes */
    ArrayList<ClienteModel> arrayClientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

        /* pega o array "dados" que vem na resposta da consulta ao rest */
    JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");

        /* percorre o array */
    for (int i = 0; i < dados.length(); i++) {

            /* pega a posição de cada linha no array */
        JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);

            /* cria um objeto do tipo ClienteModel */
        ClienteModel mClienteModel = new ClienteModel();

            /* cadastra os dados necessários no objeto mClienteModel */
        mClienteModel.set_idrm(Integer.parseInt(item.optString("id")));
        mClienteModel.set_nome(item.optString("nome"));
        mClienteModel.set_tipo(item.getString("tipo"));
        mClienteModel.set_endereco(item.optString("endereco"));
        mClienteModel.set_numero(item.optString("numero"));
        mClienteModel.set_complemento(item.optString("complemento"));
        mClienteModel.set_cep(item.optString("cep"));
        mClienteModel.set_bairro(item.optString("bairro"));
        mClienteModel.set_cidade(item.optString("cidade"));
        mClienteModel.set_estado(item.optString("estado"));
        mClienteModel.set_informacao_adicional("informacao_adicional");

        /* adicionar o objeto mClienteModel no array de Clientes "arrayClientes" */
        arrayClientes.add(mClienteModel);
    }

    return arrayClientes;

}
}
```

This is the ClientModel:

```
public class ClienteModel {

    private int _id;
    private int _idrm;
    private String _nome;
    private String _tipo;
    private String _endereco;
    private String _numero;
    private String _complemento;
    private String _cep;
    private String _bairro;
    private String _cidade;
    private String _estado;
    private String _informacao_adicional;

    public ClienteModel() {}

    public ClienteModel(String _nome, String _tipo, String _endereco, String _numero, String _complemento, String _cep, String _bairro, String _cidade, String _estado, String _informacao_adicional) {
        this._nome = _nome;
        this._tipo = _tipo;
        this._endereco = _endereco;
        this._numero = _numero;
        this._complemento = _complemento;
        this._cep = _cep;
        this._bairro = _bairro;
        this._cidade = _cidade;
        this._estado = _estado;
        this._informacao_adicional = _informacao_adicional;
    }

    public ClienteModel(int _idrm, String _nome, String _tipo, String _endereco, String _numero, String _complemento, String _cep, String _bairro, String _cidade, String _estado, String _informacao_adicional) {
        this._idrm = _idrm;
        this._nome = _nome;
        this._tipo = _tipo;
        this._endereco = _endereco;
        this._numero = _numero;
        this._complemento = _complemento;
        this._cep = _cep;
        this._bairro = _bairro;
        this._cidade = _cidade;
        this._estado = _estado;
        this._informacao_adicional = _informacao_adicional;
    }

    public ClienteModel(int _id, int _idrm, String _nome, String _tipo, String _endereco, String _numero, String _complemento, String _cep, String _bairro, String _cidade, String _estado, String _informacao_adicional) {
        this._id = _id;
        this._idrm = _idrm;
        this._nome = _nome;
        this._tipo = _tipo;
        this._endereco = _endereco;
        this._numero = _numero;
        this._complemento = _complemento;
        this._cep = _cep;
        this._bairro = _bairro;
        this._cidade = _cidade;
        this._estado = _estado;
        this._informacao_adicional = _informacao_adicional;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public int get_idrm() {
        return _idrm;
    }

    public void set_idrm(int _idrm) {
        this._idrm = _idrm;
    }

    public String get_nome() {
        return _nome;
    }

    public void set_nome(String _nome) {
        this._nome = _nome;
    }

    public String get_tipo() {
        return _tipo;
    }

    public void set_tipo(String _tipo) {
        this._tipo = _tipo;
    }

    public String get_endereco() {
        return _endereco;
    }

    public void set_endereco(String _endereco) {
        this._endereco = _endereco;
    }

    public String get_numero() {
        return _numero;
    }

    public void set_numero(String _numero) {
        this._numero = _numero;
    }

    public String get_complemento() {
        return _complemento;
    }

    public void set_complemento(String _complemento) {
        this._complemento = _complemento;
    }

    public String get_cep() {
        return _cep;
    }

    public void set_cep(String _cep) {
        this._cep = _cep;
    }

    public String get_bairro() {
        return _bairro;
    }

    public void set_bairro(String _bairro) {
        this._bairro = _bairro;
    }

    public String get_cidade() {
        return _cidade;
    }

    public void set_cidade(String _cidade) {
        this._cidade = _cidade;
    }

    public String get_estado() {
        return _estado;
    }

    public void set_estado(String _estado) {
        this._estado = _estado;
    }

    public String get_informacao_adicional() {
        return _informacao_adicional;
    }

    public void set_informacao_adicional(String _informacao_adicional) {
        this._informacao_adicional = _informacao_adicional;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClienteModel{" +
                "_id=" + _id +
                ", _idrm=" + _idrm +
                ", _nome='" + _nome + '\'' +
                ", _tipo='" + _tipo + '\'' +
                ", _endereco='" + _endereco + '\'' +
                ", _numero='" + _numero + '\'' +
                ", _complemento='" + _complemento + '\'' +
                ", _cep='" + _cep + '\'' +
                ", _bairro='" + _bairro + '\'' +
                ", _cidade='" + _cidade + '\'' +
                ", _estado='" + _estado + '\'' +
                ", _informacao_adicional='" + _informacao_adicional + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: `Log.i("RM", String.valueOf(mClientesRest.getClientes()));` did you here forgot the `toString()`?

Comment: `getClientes` cannot return anything, because `mRequestQueue.add` is asynchronous.

Comment: I need to see in the log the objects that's inside the array, what I don't is how can I print the objects. Why it is returning null?

Comment: OK @njzk2 how can I solve this?

Comment: advice,  change `Log.i("RM", String.valueOf(e.getStackTrace()));` to `Log.e("RM", e.getMessage(), e);` for better logging of errors thru Log.e

Comment: by essence, Volley is asynchronous. This is what the whole listeners thing is about. You need to be asynchronous as well (unless you absolutely want to be synchronous, but that's a lot of work for few benefits). You either need to add a system of listeners to your `getClientes`, or move the Volley listener you use outside of ClientesRest

Comment: @njzk2 can you give me an example on how to do it? I started learning android last week, I'm stuck with this code, if you could I'd appreciate that

Comment: @njzk2 I think, that if you create a sample as an answer, as the OP requested, you get the accepted. I'm curious about it too. I don't quite understood how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like that:

Define an interface for receiving the values:

```
public interface ClientesRestListener {
    public void clientesReceived(List<ClienteModel> clientes);
}
```

Then, use the interface in the `getClientes` method:

```
public final void getClientes(final ClientesRestListener listener) {
    String url = this.URL_WS + recursoRest;
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);
    JsonObjectRequest mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                List<ClienteModel> clientes = parseJSON(response);
                listener.clientesReceived(clientes);
            }
        }, /* Error listener here*/) {/* add headers here */};
    mRequestQueue.add(mJsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Modify `parseJSON` so it returns a `List<ClienteModel>`, add `return arrayClientes;` at the end, for example. (You should also make `arrayClientes` a local variable in the scope of the method, to limit the dependencies between elements)

Finally, call `getClientes`:

```
mClientesRest.getClientes(new ClientesRestListener() {
    public void clientesReceived(List<ClienteModel> clientes) {
        // Here modify to do whatever you need to do with clientes
        Log.i("RM", String.valueOf(clientes));
    }
});
```

Comment: I've edited the question, I tried to do as you said, but still getting a null result, did I miss something? thank you for your time

Comment: your edit seems about right. There could be an issue with the actual content received from the server. You need to check the return value from the server (in `onResponse`), check if there is any exception. To get the maximum information from an exception, use `e.printStackTrace();` (where `e` is your exception). It will print in the log the stack trace of the exception so you can see what happened.

Comment: among the things that can go wrong, `Integer.parseInt(item.optString("id"))`: `optString` would return `""` if `id` is not in the object, which would cause an `IllegalArgumentException` in `parseInt`.

Comment: Ok man, it solved my case, the problem was "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" and I pull it off, thank you for your help, if could have a look at my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559923/unable-to-add-window-android-dialog-box it is about the same code